# Application runs in Editor but not as .exe

Tags: java, javafx, stream, exe, packaging

I just finished a small project which is supposed to read an exel file and display it in a table view and was happy that everything worked fine when I start my application inside Intellij. When I then build my JavaFX application artifact with an .exe file the application starts but somewhere there occures an error which did not occure before.

Error message from Windows cmd:

```
    C:\Users\E0297813\IdeaProjects\Sachbearbeiter\out\artifacts\Sachbearbeiter\bundl
    es\Sachbearbeiter\app>C:\Users\E0297813\IdeaProjects\Sachbearbeiter\out\artifact
    s\Sachbearbeiter\bundles\Sachbearbeiter\runtime\bin\java.exe -jar C:\Users\E0297
    813\IdeaProjects\Sachbearbeiter\out\artifacts\Sachbearbeiter\bundles\Sachbearbei
    ter\app\Sachbearbeiter.jar
    C:\Users\E0297813\Desktop\aaaaaaaaaaa.xlsx
    Exception in Application start method
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(Lau
    ncherImpl.java:389)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImp
    l.java:328)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
    java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
    sorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherIm
    pl.java:917)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$152(
    LauncherImpl.java:182)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$50/31748187.run(Unkno
    wn Source)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/monitorjbl/xlsx/StreamingReader
            at sample.Main.search_id(Main.java:483)
            at sample.Main.createcomponents(Main.java:245)
            at sample.Main.start(Main.java:124)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$159
    (LauncherImpl.java:863)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$$Lambda$94/7771974.run(Unknow
    n Source)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$172(Platfor
    mImpl.java:326)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$46/20085625.run(Unkno
    wn Source)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$170(PlatformImpl.
    java:295)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$48/32120612.run(Unkno
    wn Source)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$171(PlatformI
    mpl.java:294)
            at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$$Lambda$47/2900468.run(Unknow
    n Source)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatch
    er.java:95)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$145(WinApplication.ja
    va:101)
            at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$36/17230114.run(Unknown S
    ource)
            ... 1 more
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.monitorjbl.xlsx.StreamingReader

        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 17 more
Exception running application sample.Main

C:\Users\E0297813\IdeaProjects\Sachbearbeiter\out\artifacts\Sachbearbeiter\bundl
es\Sachbearbeiter\app>pause
Drücken Sie eine beliebige Taste . . .
```

Why didnt show it up when I tried to run it in IntelliJ?
Does it have something to do with my JDK and JRE versions which might not be the right?

I have no idea what the problem could be.

If you need any further information please tell me what you need.

Thank you for any help

Comment: Add stacktraces as text not as image

Comment: Im sorry I changed it

Comment: Check the jar file, if it contains the class. Also show us how you call the program

Comment: There's a good explanation of ClassNotFoundException at [DZone](https://dzone.com/articles/java-classnotfoundexception-vs-noclassdeffounderro) site

Comment: The jar does contain the class. What excatly do you mean how I call the program? I way Start the program is listed at the top of my error message.